# Python regex with variable inside pattern in webpage

Tags: python, html, regex

I need to search in a webpage code for a pattern which contains two variables: one known and one that I'm trying to retrieve.

```py
def getcpu():
    parse()
    for child in rt.iter('proc'):
        proc = child.attrib['name']
        cpumodel= proc.replace('(R)',"").replace('(TM)','').replace('CPU','')
    return cpumodel

def passmark():
   url = urlopen('https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu_list.php').read().decode('utf-8')
   cpu = getcpu()
   soup =  BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")
   score = soup.find(text=cpu)
   print(score)
```

so var1 is known and has to be used for the search and var2 should be retrieved in some way(code doesn't work, of course). I just put var2 in there because I'm trying to explain what I want to achieve.
Is it possible? Or any other way other than regex?

edit:
a better example. let's say a line in the webpage code is:

```html
<TR id="cpu793"><TD><A HREF="cpu_lookup.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i5-2400+%40+3.10GHz&amp;id=793">Intel Core i5-2400 @ 3.10GHz</A></TD><TD>5965</TD><TD>662</TD><TD><a href="cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i5-2400+%40+3.10GHz&amp;id=793#price">41.15</a></TD><TD><ahref="cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i5-2400+%40+3.10GHz&amp;id=793#price">$144.99*</a></TD></TR>
```

Intel Core i5-2400 @ 3.10GHz is var1 and based on that I'm trying to get var2 (which in this line is 5965)

Comment: Why don't you use Beautiful Soup or lxml? With those libraries you can select elements based on attributes, position, text-content, etc.

Comment: how would that work for my case? updated the question , to make it a bit clearer what I'm trying to get

Comment: Using Beautiful Soup you would select an element that has text: "Intel Core i5-2400 @ 3.10GHz", then select the next element. Pseudocode: `soup.find(text='Intel Core i5-2400 @ 3.10GHz').next`

Comment: I'd highly recommend beautifulsoup here!

Comment: I highly recommend to use XPath as another option apart from the ones they have suggested you in the previous comments, as it offers a simple way to access tag attributes. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp

Comment: t.m.adam, the code works using text, but how do I make it to use a variable instead? it returns None if removing .next. using .next gives 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: any clue if there is anything to be done when text =  variable that comes from a function? the function prints fine, has a return, but when used in soup.find is always None type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, consider using BeautifulSoup:

```py
html = '''<TR id="cpu793"><TD><A HREF="cpu_lookup.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i5-2400+%40+3.10GHz&amp;id=793">Intel Core i5-2400 @ 3.10GHz</A></TD><TD>5965</TD><TD>662</TD><TD><a href="cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i5-2400+%40+3.10GHz&amp;id=793#price">41.15</a></TD><TD><ahref="cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i5-2400+%40+3.10GHz&amp;id=793#price">$144.99*</a></TD></TR>'''
var1 = 'Intel Core i5-2400 @ 3.10GHz'
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
result = soup.find(text=var1)
if result:
    var2 = result.next.text
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Comment: still no go. Updated the main code. my var1 is from a function that returns the processor model. I print that I get the correct output wich is the same as 'Intel Core i5-2400 @ 3.10GHz'. I use it in my function , soup.find returns none

Comment: In my answer, I use the example that you provided (the most recent one). Did you get the expected results when you ran my code?

Comment: always prints Not found.

Comment: that very code works, maybe my var1 wich results from a function isn't a string?

Comment: How do I know? You have to check its type.

Comment: I'm printing the getcpu() function and I'm getting exactly the same as var1 : Intel Core i5-2400 @ 3.10GHz, but when I try to use it this way inside the soup.find it returns None